# Storyboard layout for iphone 5 and 4

Tags: objective-c, layout, storyboard

Currently I am realising the login screen of my app. It contains 3 image views, one for the logo and two for spacer images, and it contains 2 buttons. Everything has custom images.

It looks like this (the lines are the spacer views):
[image]

Now I am struggeling how to center this. The center of the screen should be exactly between the two buttons. But how can I realise this for the 3.5inch and 4inch screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any requirements for the minimum SDK? If you can use iOS 6 as a baseline look into AutoLayout. Should be able to get your job done.

If not you can put your buttons in a common  `container` view, then be sure to set

```
container.center = self.view.center
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method of that ViewController.

Comment: I am already using the AutoLayout, is there the possiblity to say one constrain equals antoher so the the constraint above and below the views are equal. This would center the group of elements